# Directional Run Length Decoding

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

We all know run-length decoding: A list of character-length pairs expands to a string of that many characters, so `A1B4C2` expands to `ABBBBCC`. But what if we stretch this concept to 2 dimensions?

Instead of character-length pairs, in this challenge you will be given character-length-direction triples. For example, using N/S/E/W to indicate direction, the input `A4E B5S C3W D3N E1W` should yield the output

```
AAAAB   
    B
 E  B
 D  B
 D  B
 DCCC
```

You can take input in any reasonable format (such as a list of `(char, length, N/E/S/W)` like shown here, or perhaps `(0/1/2/3, length, char)`).

The input will not overlap itself, so `A5E B3W` or `A5E B4S C4W D4N` is invalid input.

The input will also not expand past the left or top edges of the string, only the bottom and right edges will be expanded.

The character will always be within the printable ASCII range.

Consistent trailing or leading whitespace that does not affect the presentation of the output is fine.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest submission per language, measured in bytes, wins.

Here are a couple cases to test your entry against:

```
A4E B5S C3W D3N E1W
AAAAB   
    B
 E  B
 D  B
 D  B
 DCCC

A4E B5S C3W D3N -2E -1N  2W |1S
AAAAB   
 |  B
 ---B
 D  B
 D  B
 DCCC

.3S  2E ,3N  2E .5S
.   . 
. , .  
. , .  
  , .   
    .

>6E v3S <6W ^2N >5E v1S <5W
>>>>>>v 
>>>>>vv
^<<<<<v
^<<<<<<
```

[And here's an example implementation in JavaScript.](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hVPBjpswEFWvfMWIk1HAWpJmtdKGSG2XnqocyoEDpRIiZkNKTQp2lajJl-wlh_aj2tv-yKpjGxJ2K6WRItvj996M5w0PP3m9ZMfjLykK7-bPq8dC8lyUNYdl2TC9y6qPkn9g_F6s7liOaFLyjQM_LIC85q2ArGkggCS9xUjFBGzxdNUfdv2hqBsgSb7KGhcvlJp7zpFCXcBJtgMreqnpuMw6Eu5Hox4GKneyS2G_7wtQv7IAYi6oIcEsgO2ZNNBfG_016m9xUdIdcyPbFbHBdnrVw7OUyTZFqnrOMOvpQRAEAdih7WA3RgH4F0CxBnmXQRGCdv9TWmjQWUlVrP4NE7LhqvBb69A7_WTMw6ZLgS9p2DeJasQuWtuhDcuW78uKRTuekysXbCTdqFboxhlmVXLW2SYFbTdVKYj9idvOcDZ0WE0HpVQRtEfmKl9J_qXFO43BlEuZM0JM2AXOtsKBYN65pp5rrmgmiOc7vbXq5ROnUzOuJWlnGqtaBs9ZGqC1DaTrjQGp0MGFJEmNgilUNWOnzdZCX7MNGQyynuJUV9oFR-foUKSVlerEhe9KJzpx6orRqr4nqm3_BI2crkX7gNnVStd1yYmNHnQ77cdLsnMag-Pv_M3rEN5OI3g3ieFusoDQj62XMW8cgucvAMYx7P3IopMI9yG4k4Ve6TSy5tchfMf47DqGz-MFzKd49vE8jU2uvw)

Comment: Can the directions be taken as a certain set of constants replacing NESW, eg. 0/2/4/6?

Comment: @mathscat yes, that’s what I was going for. But don’t abuse it and say that e.g. you’re using “x++” for E and “y++” for S

Comment: Is the next challenge to encode the output??

Comment: @MarkStewart I’m not sure how that would work, an arbitrary string could be encoded like this in a variety of ways

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 120 bytes

```python
def f(A):
 G=[];X=Y=0
 for c,n,(x,y)in A:
  for _ in" "*n:G+=[[]];G[Y]+=[_]*(X-~len(G[Y]));G[Y][X]=c;X+=x;Y+=y
 return G
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9BToQwFIb3nOKlq3amTCCjiYF0gUrYzWYWQJpmFgxozaSQUiLE6EXcsNELeADP4W1smTFx1ff9f_O_979_dpN5bNU8fwym8W9-xmPdQIMTEnmQMS7igpUs8KBpNVRUUTzSiUgFifUX8QBSIUArFWVrxrkQccZLYceDWOHCfzvVCjuFkMXghWBVXKzZGJdrNnmgazNoBdll_7dUvdFDZWSremA2vBsMJpu-O0n7eg9aHq3cYI5HHghqPxg7hZEfCkLhBVCKIsAhhcAiyh34f7R3FFAIHewu4IcEXvnIbYAgS6XRhsL_OwTxnK7bZ-e4E1x7gE677QhtnlqpsLUJOdeYv5KrFG6v93C3zeF-u4M0zM_WLw)

- -29 bytes thanks to [noodle man](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/108687/noodle-man)
- -2 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)

Comment: `X=0;Y=0` -> `X=Y=0` and `if len(G)<=Y:G+=[[]]` -> `G+=(len(G)<=Y)*[[]]`

Comment: [134 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZCxTsMwEIb3PMXJk69xqkQFCSV4CFBl69KhiSyLoW3AqHIixxGpEIy8BEsXeAEegOfgbWqnRWKy__873f13H1_t3j42-nD47G0dXf2-b7Y11DTHNICCC5mVvOJxAHVjYM00owPbo9KQOz6a96A0ATLRaRFyuttqWuA1r3AihJRZISoZcuEK5ISW0dvInYc4IlFKvs7KkA9ZFfJ9AGZre6OhOKf5Ubqzpl9b1egOuBvV9pbitGt3yr3Bg1EbZ9dU0EHEkrkC635JGiUSGbwAmZMUaMIgdpKsvIj-1NKrmEHixeIsogThVQzCNZA4Lji4pvA_h8TA-6Z59sRH8LcAaI2fTsj0qVGaOox4WuPwnV_M4eZyCbezFdzNFjBPVid0BA)

Comment: @noodleman oh neat, thanks!

Comment: [122 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9BToQwFIb3nOKlq3amTCCjiYF0gUrYzWYWQJrGBQNaMymklAgavYgbNnoBD-A5vI0tMyau-r7_b977__fPbjIPrZrnj8E0_tXP86FuoMEJiTzIGBdxwUoWeNC0GiqqKB7pRKSCxPqLeAdSIUArFWVrxrkQccZLYUcrihUu_LdjrbDTCFksXghWxcWajXG5ZpMHujaDVpCdE3xL1Rs9VEa2qgdm13eDwWTTd0dpX-9ey4OVG8zxyANB7QdjpzDyQ0EovABKUQQ4pBBYRLkD_4_2jgIKoYPdGfyQwCsfuV0gyFJqtEvhfw5BPKfr9sk5LoLrD9Bpdx2hzWMrFbY2Iaca81dykcL15R5utjncbneQhvnJ-gU) by opting to have a lot of extra whitespace

Comment: @noodleman I considered that but I didn't know if that counted as consistent whitespace lol, thanks for clarifying that

Comment: You might as well use `_` for `" "` since you're assigning it

Comment: @xnor Oh huh, good point lol

Answer (score 7):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＷＳ✳§ι⁰×§ι¹Ｉ✂ι²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/788IzMnVUHDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU1MhAMgo0XDJLEpNLsnMz9NwLPHMS0mt0MjUUTDQ1NRRCMnMTS1GFjUECjonFpdoBOdkJqeCRIw0gcD6//8gOzMulzJjLh8bM67QOCOuIDtTIN8QyDfl@q9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated triples using a leading `UDLR` instead of a trailing `NSEW`. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ
```

Loop over each triple.

```
✳§ι⁰
```

Output in the direction given by the first character.

```
×§ι¹Ｉ✂ι²
```

Output the required character repeated by the length.

Comment: Right language for the job

Comment: If you use the version of Charcoal on ATO you can alternatively use `2640` instead of `UDLR`.

Comment: And it should go without saying that Charcoal has no problem with inputs that cause overlapping or negative coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 13 bytes

```
ṫ⅛ƛy›Y;¾J⟑÷ø∧
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLhuavihZvGm3nigLpZO8K+SuKfkcO3w7jiiKciLCIiLCJbW1wiQVwiLCA0LCAyXSxbXCJCXCIsIDUsIDRdLFtcIkNcIiwgMywgNl0sW1wiRFwiLCAzLCAwXSxbXCItXCIsIDIsIDJdLFtcIi1cIiwgMSwgMF0sW1wiIFwiLCAyLCA2XSxbXCJ8XCIsIDEsIDRdXSJd)

Vyxal does have a built-in canvas (fork of 05AB1E's canvas element), but it partially overwrites the drawn characters, so the input has to be modified.
Takes in input as a list of `[char, length, direction (0/2/4/6)]`.

```
ṫ⅛ƛy›Y;¾J⟑÷ø∧
ṫ⅛              # Push tail to global array
  ƛ   ;         # For all other elements ...
   y›Y          # Uninterleave, increment, interleave (increment the middle)
       ¾J       # Push global array (wraps tail in list), join with rest
         ⟑      # Map through list
          ÷ø∧   # Draw modified input to canvas
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 156 bytes

```perl
sub f{($o,$p,$c,$n,$d,@r)=@_;@_%3?$n?do{$$o[$p]=$c;f($o,$p+1+{N,-99,S,97,W,-2}->{$d},--$n?($c,$n,$d):(),@r)}:"@$o"=~s/.{98}/$&\n/gr:f([(' ')x1e4],$"='',@_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVPNbtpAEL7vU4ycbdcoa1tATAsG4gTopRVI0CiHkCAX1sQteF3b0FSO8xK99NBDny0vQnfXkFhRq45kf579Zr75sR2xeGXvdsnmE/iZjjnFEcVzikOKF9SNKx135rizV/VTHJ4ueIYxv8LRdQfPHb@IPq4eZ0NqNJt0Qptv6CU1arnRzfAip4YhkvSDWqWlV6Ri3tJczLXOQ2KZWfNtbuHX09Baxi1fv9IJkMpdlZ1cU6x1CKHurJLv1t8B@16wcpDPYx1dkbOTAaFAzu2JhF79UkK/PpQwqEqv3SbkmqIzYecAgMQF5wgG6t4v33u9HvqPpFFTnFFVHtQUd1@d/K3OvVI1DOMfdcz6pBBRkrQ@LHmmXZI0hZwJAqiAZ4QCi4lMqdhtqORtIdxuqO5uakq4axdcteDs0mq6yrZQPGy36KYt7YBthCqZLCKXz@4iNk/ZAjoQ8QhcPHP2lBuE0SYV52svggySaBWklgV5OQYvuYzw9UN0xUGSKsk@QGJNk2NsWeulA0daj4dJkKQsTCGNxZsPwiXwGFbMW8jHb7dBypLImzNIb70UFpwlSlFWUvZS0TTNUHCe74uKIolBFLNE6HtpwEPgvjrjm1T2FyTgByEzNXSYQMRuVnKI557Z16LcKRD@hUAL5N8hv9IOGY4@wug9yZ8WoMZO0lgIfOZBqN68WJhG8IxotNiKCo7iQIysGU92KD0NtXKAymg9C@/poz19aLI1DZ8afqEgWpesAEXkaH8uPFr8bXKyx5@/YTAej8YTeDe6GPblnOTx1w/wViuWwHKTillkjrMbdxuov62jD@0GuripoXHXFn5V@Db6Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 42 bytes

```
1 :'#&u@[[`]`(u:@32$~1+>./@])}[:}:0+/\@,#'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dU_BTsJAFLzvVwxi3NbC0m1pI5valG7ryfQghx5qAWMgysULbTyAP-IFD34U3-EP-FrQ4MHZzJt9Lzuzee8fq93-YdRRsvQ7asQ5y2IBCcW7F1VUwAjEICo3opiXc6NSkeucv0mrUKEYbKLS3JqF2irbGtxHvS5nZ4Ivca3A0YMNRewL6Lvbm89qvexf7S9_g__mhc0n5vY06-j4Mtni8ekFQ3hw6UgYfBzrJOVLE5aAvZI0s1cziVmjsn1Oa7Qunxw-HPJKosHDOpgS__MeO8YWr89ryhgPU8TeBNrNkbgZUpmzMSEGwIiIGdK2JqdVa81CP0XtThD4OaZOhtCjXlLv5SxsUeNwqWs2DRr8aHBYfbc76Dc)

A J adverb, which modifies the list of characters to produce a verb that takes the counts as a left arg and the directions as the right arg, as complex numbers in list form.

- `[:}:0+/\@,#` Duplicate each direction by the counts, add `0 0` as a starting point, scan sum, and remove last.
- `#&u@[` Also duplicate the characters by the counts.
- `u:@32$~1+>./@]` Create a canvas of spaces of the appropriate size.
- `` [`]`...)} `` Update the canvas at the points computed by the scan sum, using the duplicated characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>207</del> <del>166</del> 149 bytes

Port of [@hyper-neutrino♦'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266285/110802) in Scala.

Saved so many bytes thanks to the comment of @noodle man and @Kjetil S

---

Golfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVE9b9swEEVX_4qDltzBlCDBLVBYloE08VCgyeIWHgyhYPXBUFUol6ITGYbn_oJOXbIkS39R-mtKSqkDEzge8N4d393j76c24zWf_Fl7vmruuVZe-nzZfKuKzMAVlwr2oxHc8RrKKX6SrVnjxQ3X7KMyDN1lgyhN5svix9qFY9OUIHncmtJ___yLJ_P9HdcomGQVJXhaiMRCFlJcNhoxY4phx3ZEM5_HX2d-aBpQfkR7kYjpuJfv25BiiwTbTc5NkWPFBFYUbHj-ucFoLNkZnNGRlSwjiuU46eJqnOziQywOw3B_3_wEyIsSbu2iyLVop3CuNd-tl0ZLJVKawhclDSTWBbDH-ZBLbb2RjbriG0vYG3sOwFt44M8BIwYhsf_gagD9U3Q5oCGD6BW8PoJ25x6ko6xUrdHbXri1ss4L9M7fLjwG3od3S5cuJiuXLifXLi2ilffaLrTMbVuJ1mjADmb-yYsEO1nUuWXQDgld0NYyK9wmXVAXSpgb8O2kgWncn594gLaCt8ZSg2lEg2ovpJt7J-XUCTaWNrVyYHD7_aXa1h5GL__x8DDkfw)

```scala
a=>{var(g,i,j)=(Seq[Seq[Char]](),0,0);for((c,n,(x,y))<-a;_<-0to n-1){g=g:+List[Char]();g=g.updated(j,g(j).padTo(1+i,' ').updated(i,c));i+=x;j+=y;};g}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVNda9swFH3oW37FqV8qUdkkZIMSmkHWhjBo-xJGYkoYmj8Sra4cZGV1KP0le-nL-qP6aybJip2N-eHK95xzda91rF9vVcILPnx9_b3TeXjxfnJafv-RJRq3XEg894A0y5GTyQg3otL35GrDFcMXqRmIiyZQuqKed8FqViuMXT3wkyvMTPavgNCWXhq632Zxm-WlAiEJgzTtaoY9pbgMMaF-a6_4ZsE-dlKLArIjAZGDzKIik2u9weUYMXWjzDA6RzeKn8Q-TxtRZKaGxPSobOnLot025TpLScxgJXabM5x15f9VtfmSIaGdeInzMeo2jW269-lLr4uznn3zXjwaYwhX62qEiVJ8fz_XSsi1deCrFPro1AukQhkvRSlv-dYQJhK_fTANEH4CGTD0KTuAiwYM_0bnDdpnGHTgXQuGg-aLaNtWyEqrnWtced9JMPkwDRiCzx_ndrkaLuxyPbyzy3SwCLrytRKpKcuJ87a23h7vSLEXWZEahpghUUdVIZLMfkl9cCw0k0a6dP_n8RkQo-CVNlRzaNSb4Rqp8sm2st0ptobWhbRg9Pjg1c6Gl-am-AtzuDh_AA)

```scala
object Main {
  def f(A: List[(Char, Int, (Int, Int))]): List[List[Char]] = {
    var G = List[List[Char]]()
    var X = 0
    var Y = 0
    for ((c, n, (x, y)) <- A) {
      for (_ <- 0 until n) {
        if (G.length <= Y) G = G :+ List[Char]()
        while (G(Y).length <= X) G = G.updated(Y, G(Y) :+ ' ')
        G = G.updated(Y, G(Y).updated(X, c))
        X += x
        Y += y
      }
    }
    G
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val directionMap = Map(
      "E" -> (1, 0),
      "W" -> (-1, 0),
      "S" -> (0, 1),
      "N" -> (0, -1)
    )
    val instructions = List("A4E", "B5S", "C3W", "D3N", "E1W")
    val grid = f(for (x <- instructions) yield (x(0), x.slice(1, x.length - 1).toInt, directionMap(x.last.toString)))
    for (row <- grid) println(row.mkString)
  }
}
```

Comment: I’ve never used Scala before but I found a `padTo` method which brings this down to 171 bytes with some extra white space removed: `a=>{var g=List[List[Char]]()
var i=0
var j=0
for((c,n,(x,y))<-a;_<-0until n){if(g.length<=j)g=g:+List[Char]()
g=g.updated(j,g(j).padTo(1+i,' ').updated(i,c))
i+=x
j+=y}
g}` (ATO link too long to fit in this comment)

Comment: You can shave off 13 chars with `var(g,i,j)=(List[List[Char]](),0,0)` and replacing all `List` with `Seq` and `.length` with `.size`

Comment: [150](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVHLbtswEESv_oqFLtmFKUGCW6CwLAN5-FCgycUtfDCMgtGDoaJQLkWnMgyf-we99OJL8k_p15SUEgcmwF1gZpeznP373KS84qPDy1V9W-apgWsuFewGA3jkFRRj_Cobs8TLO67ZF2UYumAv0SqZzvOfS3cdu1oRJE8bU_ifX_7wZLp75BoFk6ykBE8LkVjIQoqLWiOmTDFs2ZZo4vP4x8QPN8rIChTtRCLGw06_60OKLRJs1hk3eYYlE1hSsObZtxqjoWRncEZHVrKUKJbDpI3LYbKN97HY99P9-_AbIMsLeLA_Ra5FM4Zzrfl2OTdaKrGiMXxX0kBibQB7nBGZ1NYcWatrvraEjdhxAN7MA38KGDEIib2Bix70T9F5j4YMonfw5gj6EXUgHWWlaozedMKNlXVeoHf-ceYx8C4-zV26HC1cuhrduDSLFt57u9Ays20FWqcBW5j4Jy8SbGVeZZZBOyS0QVPJNHc_aYMqV8LcgW8nDUztln7iAdoK3hhL9aYR9aqdkK5_OSmnTrC2tKmUA4OH-9dqW7sfvO7jcOjzfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 131 bytes

```
{for(;$2--;y+=/S$/-/N$/){g[+x,+y]=$1;x>X&&X=x;y>Y&&Y=y;x+=/E$/-/W$/}}END{for(y=-1;y++<Y;print"")for(x=0;x<=X;)printf"%1s",g[x++,y]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBC4IwGIDhuz9jrJHMsZZ1mp9QuY5ePKiIhy6KBCoqtSH@9ZZ6fXl4X9@3tXPVDUeJz4xJQ4EnmDMeY@7OdUG1R00JWEgdZoRkoKUJc0JyMFKvVm02xXxZVBztHwNMrBsa5LIfmnZCyN2yhpPUAWTS3WuFDmJEXl1oSj1TLtbeLsq5XxPn4adO5MeOEqn9df3UdO1o2eeZwB8)

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 29 [bytes](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)

```
{/⟜{⌾(⊸⊑)""↑˜1+⌈´}·+`⊸-/}
```

Try it [here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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).

Defines a 1-modifier which takes the lengths as left argument, the directions (as a list of `⟨dx,dy⟩` pairs) as right argument, and the characters as a list (string) in the role of the function  being modified.

Explanation:

The basic idea is to [replicate](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/replicate.html#replicate) both the characters and the directions by the lengths, do a prefix sum on the directions to get the list of indices corresponding to each character, and then use [structural under](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/doc/under.html#structural-under) to index into a blank array and place the characters at their corresponding indices.

```
{/⟜{⌾(⊸⊑)""↑˜1+⌈´}·+`⊸-/} #
                           /  # The directions replicated by lengths
                       +`⊸-   # subtracted from its own prefix sum (shifts right so starts with 0‿0)
                     }·       # becomes right argument  to inner function.
 /⟜                          # The characters replicated by lengths
    {                         # becomes left argument  to inner function.
                  ⌈´         # Get the maximum x,y values from the indices,
                1+            # add 1 to get the shape of the output,
            ""↑˜              # and take from empty string to get the blank character array.
      ⌾(⊸⊑)                  # Pick out the indices in the array
                             # and place the characters.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>119</s> 116 bytes

```javascript
A=>A.map(([c,n,[x,y]])=>{for(_=0;_<n;_++){G[Y]=[...(G[Y]??[]).join``.padEnd(X)];G[Y][X]=c;X+=x;Y+=y}},G=[],X=Y=0)&&G
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVLLbtswEAR69A_0utAhIGGKsKw6CKrQgduqvvmig2ywrCNIVKxWpVw9Ahuuv6SXoGg_Kv2aUqQQIOmJw9nd2eEuf_5WVSYffuXsT9fm7tVju2DzBf2W7BHiKVGEH8hRCMzmp7yq0ZZNgu21CrbjMT4t-UYwTilFPbq54QLTL1Whbm_pPslClaE1FkEf42vB0mA9ZodgM2bH85ksGRdkzTZsgi8ulrb331ev00o1LRRq37XAoJbfu6KWyMkbB9NaJtnHopTRUaVoQsDRRVcODkbaGCBbWRZKQpVbBdrsy6JFziflYAynEYBNMrSW7633BSJ4CqW7Tn1tdMzk6JZZl0qELE1AyUOLgc2NGECRwxCiSYtcD9NSqrt2B4wx8PGgRvdds0N6OIEpkmUj4XmVSTDaNqWWbVerIamnzgQ4F1bBGu2HcdQ-B6FhX7ukJqA9EMiKWhinAzk27AnCt8A9AhNBINbQHfBKYz1S19M4stgTcOa9zPO2TVf2s8uRcfAUqkpJy-oO9fP8j7RVxqRZkLbVn-azIEcvZ0BmUS-LNXG2_-PhMV28CeHdLIL3fgwf_BWEXjx6ybnTUD9kBTCN4YcXjagfaRwC8VfmpLNoNL8M4V7z15cxfJ6uYD7Td0_fZ7Ht9Q8)

This is a golfed version of the example implementation I provided. It takes the input as a list of `[char, length, [dx, dy]]`.

Explanation:

```javascript
A.map(([c,n,[x,y]])=>{ ... },G=[],X=Y=0)&&G
```

This first assigns G (a 2d array of characters) to an empty list and X and Y both to 0. It returns G after first running the following on each character `c`, length `n`, dx `x`, and dy `y`:

```javascript
for(_=0;_<n;_++){ ... }
```

Run `n` times:

```javascript
G[Y]=[...(G[Y]??[]).join``.padEnd(X)];
```

Pad the Y'th list in G to length X with spaces.

```javascript
G[Y][X]=c;
```

Set the X'th character of the Y'th list in G to `c`.

```javascript
X+=x;Y+=y
```

Add `x` to X and `y` to Y.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ā¤Ê+ŠΛ
```

-1 byte thanks to *@CommandMaster*

Inputs as three separated lists of the same length: \$lengths,directions,characters\$, where the \$directions\$ are `0246` for `NESW` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOOhJYe7tI8uODf7//9oEx1THWMgNNIxBOFYrmgjHRMdMx0DIM8ASJsARZQclXSUnIDYGYhdgFgXihWAuEYpFgA)

If the input as a list of triplets is mandatory, it's **8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)** instead:

```
ø`ā¤Ê+rΛ
```

Inputs as a list of triplets \$[direction,char,length]\$, where the \$directions\$ are again `0246` for `NESW` respectively.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8I6EI42Hlhzu0i46N/v//@hoIx0lRyUdk1idaBMdJSclHVMgy0xHyVlJxxjIMtBRcoGwgOp0lXSMIGJAliFEnQJEDKi3BiQWCwA)

**Explanation:**

```python
ā        # Implicitly push the first input-list of lengths, and then
         # push a list in the range [1,list-length], without popping the list
 ¤       # Push its last item (the list-length) without popping the list
  Ê      # NOT-equals check on each value, so we'll have a list of [1,1,...,1,0]
   +     # Add the values at the same positions of the top two lists together
    Š    # Triple-swap to push the list of characters and directions from the third and
         # second inputs implicitly
     Λ   # Use the Canvas builtin with these three lists as arguments
         # (after which the result is output immediately)
```

```python
ø        # Zip/transpose; swapping rows/columns of the implicit input-list of triplets
 `       # Pop and push all three lists separately to the stack
  ā¤Ê+   # Same as above to change the top list of lengths
      r  # Reverse the order of the three lists on the stack
       Λ # Use the Canvas builtin with these three lists as arguments
         # (after which the result is output immediately)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine to understand how the Canvas builtin works](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210), and why we increase the lengths (except for the last one) by 1 first.

Comment: [`II` ->`Š` and swapping the second and third input lines for -1](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//SOOhJYe7tI8uODf7//9oEx1THWMgNNIxBOFYrmgjHRMdMx0DIM8ASJsARZQclXSUnIDYGYhdgFgXihWAuEYpFgA)